# How to mock third party modules with Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I've got current import in my test target:

```
import sharp from 'sharp'
```

and using it with in my same test target:

```
return sharp(local_read_file)
    .raw()
    .toBuffer()
    .then(outputBuffer => {
```

In my test, I'm doing below to mock sharp functions:

```
jest.mock('sharp', () => {
  raw: jest.fn()
  toBuffer: jest.fn()
  then: jest.fn()
})
```

but I'm getting:

```
  return (0, _sharp2.default)(local_read_file).
                             ^
TypeError: (0 , _sharp2.default) is not a function
```

Is there a way we can mock all Sharp module functions using Jest with the function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to mock it like this :

```
jest.mock('sharp', () => () => ({
        raw: () => ({
            toBuffer: () => ({...})
        })
    })
```

First you need to return function instead of an object, cause you call `sharp(local_read_file)`. This function call will return an object with key `raw` which holds another function and so on.

To test on the every of your functions was called you need to create a spy for every of the function. As you can't to this in the initial mock call, you can mock it initially with a spy and add the mocks later on:

```
jest.mock('sharp', () => jest.fn())

import sharp from 'sharp' //this will import the mock

const then = jest.fn() // create mock `then` function
const toBuffer = jest.fn(()=> ({then})) // create mock for `toBuffer` function that will return the `then` function
const raw = jest.fn(()=> ({toBuffer})) // create mock for `raw` function that will return the `toBuffer` function
sharp.mockImplementation(()=> ({raw})) // make `sharp` to return the `raw` function
```

Comment: How do I now use spyon to get callcount and args on it (sharp)?  Can I actually do this? `const sharpSpy = jest.spyOn("sharp", "raw")
      expect(sharpSpy).toBeCalled();
      expect(sharpSpy.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);` This seem to fail in my test

Comment: This needs to be a bit more complicate way of mocking it. I will update my answer.

Comment: I get `TypeError: (0 , _sharp2.default)(...).raw is not a function` error when I use that method by adding mocks later on.

Comment: Argh, you are right it must return an object not just the function, updated my answer.

Comment: I still seem to get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined` any ideas why?

Comment: any help would be great here

Comment: ah, I just forgot the `()` around `{raw}` and the other returning objects. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks it works but how do I get number of times a particular mock is called then? I have something like ```test("sharp being called", () => {
      imageResizer.lambda_handler(records)
      expect(sharp).toBeCalled();
      expect(sharp.raw.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
    })``` but it seems to not pick up how many times ```sharp``` has been called this is the mock ```sharp.mockImplementation(()=> ({raw}))```

Comment: any help would be great here