# How to do unit testing for a function calling a private function , which makes an external API call in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, chai

How to do unit testing for a function calling a private function , which makes an external API call in nodejs. What i want is that my test should not be dependent on response from an external call and I thought of mocking the private function through which API call is made but I can't seem to achieve that. What should be a good approach to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can mock/stub the package you are using to call the external API (http, request, etc). By doing that, you don't need to depend on any external resource, and also, you don't need to change you code to expose and override/mock the private function code.

Comment: How can i stub request because when I require it , it comes as a function without being associated to an object.

Comment: What are you using for unit testing? I use Jest for unit testing in JS, so I do things like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158728/how-to-mock-third-party-modules-with-jest

Comment: I use mocha and sinon