# Testing sharp with memfs error: [Error: Input file is missing]

Tags: sharp

I had trouble testing my code that implement [`sharp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) and [`memfs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memfs). I has codes that download image and cropping it to certain dimension. I use [`sharp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) to achieve the cropping. When it comes testing, I use `jest` and [`memfs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memfs). My test code has 2 parts:

1. Download a image and save to mock volume/fileSystem that created with `memfs`.
2. Cropping the downloaded image to certain dimension with `sharp`.

Part 1 worked perfectly, was able to download image to the fake volume and asserted with `jest` (exist in the fake volume).
**But part 2 gave me error**:`[Error: Input file is missing]`.

```
const sizeToCrop = {
            width: 378,
            height: 538,
            left: 422,
            top: 0,
        };

sharp(`./downloadedImage.jpg`)
            .extract(sizeToCrop)
            .toFile(`./CroppedImage.jpg`)
            .then(() => {
                console.log(`resolve!`);
            })
            .catch((err: Error) => {
                console.log(err);
                return Promise.reject();
            });

// Error message: [Error: Input file is missing]
```

But when I test it with real volume. It worked fine.
Anyone has idea how to solve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**After some inspirations from [here](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/2877), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56589770/mocking-a-node-module-which-uses-chained-function-calls-with-jest-in-node) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46158728/how-to-mock-third-party-modules-with-jest)**.

It is because `sharp` is not accessing `memfs`' faked file system, it is accessing the actual `fs`' file system, which `./donwloadedImage.jpg` to not exist. Hence, in order to make `sharp` use `memfs`, it has to be mocked. And `extract` and `toFile` functions need to be mocked as well(for chaining function call):

```
// Inside code.test.ts

jest.mock('sharp', () => {
    const sharp = jest.requireActual('sharp');
    const { vol } = require('memfs');
    let inputFilePath: string;
    let sizeToCrop: any;
    let outputFilePath: string;
    const toFile = async (writePath: string): Promise<any> => {
        outputFilePath = writePath;
        try {
            return await starCropping();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error in mocked toFile()`, error);
        }
    };
    const extract = (dimensionSize: string): any => {
        sizeToCrop = dimensionSize;
        return { toFile };
    };
    const mockSharp = (readPath: string): any => {
        inputFilePath = readPath;
        return { extract };
    };
    async function starCropping(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            const inputFile = vol.readFileSync(inputFilePath);
            const imageBuffer = await sharp(inputFile).extract(sizeToCrop).toBuffer();
            vol.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, imageBuffer);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error in mocked sharp module`, error);
            return Promise.reject();
        }
    }

    return mockSharp;
});
```